# Is core.hookspath not working on windows?

Tags: git

I am trying to change the hooksPath on my windows machine but it doesn't seem to work. The hook is working perfectly whenever I remove the global setting made via

```
git config --global core.hooksPath '/code/.githooks'
```

but as soon as it is active, no hook is executed anymore. I tried different paths like for example

```
git config --global core.hooksPath '~/.githooks'
```

and put the needed folder into my user account but it didn't work either.

I tried to use a more windows-like style like the following but it doesn't help either:

```
git config --global core.hooksPath 'C:\Code\.githooks'
```

And I removed the '.' (dot) just in case this could cause any trouble, for example:

```
git config --global core.hooksPath 'C:\Code\MyGitHooks'
git config --global core.hooksPath '/Code/MyGitHooks'
```

All folders and files are in place whenever I change the setting!

**One note:** I use the possibility to use .net for hook implementation. But as the hooks are working fine in the default directory this shouldn't be a problem, right?

Has anyone succeeded in setting this up on windows? Or is it just not possible?
Thanks a lot for any insights!

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: `~` is an idiom for *nix based operating systems, not for Windows. Encode the full path for the location. `'c:\whatever\.githooks'` Whether hookspath work on windows or not I have no idea.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, unfortunately this doesn't help, either. Just tried it again. I'll update my question.

Comment: And just to be sure (you see a lot of odd questions here on SO), that folder exists, and contains parameterless bash-scripts to use for hooks?

Comment: Files and folder exist! And I updated my question to state that I am using a .net .exe file for hook implementation. But as it works in the default folder this shouldn't be a problem, I guess.

Comment: I just tried it here with a simple pre-commit script that exits with 1, does not abort the commit, so you're right, something seems to be amiss here.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, that's exactly the hook I am playing around with to keep things simple. Thank you for confirming the described behavior on your side! So mmh, do we have a bug here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[dscho](https://github.com/dscho) from the git for windows team [helped me isolate the problem](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1420). The problem was my quoting (''). I didn't use bash but cmd as command line and cmd has different quoting rules (""). If I execute

> git config --global core.hooksPath C:\Path\To\Hooks

or

> git config --global core.hooksPath "C:\Path\To\Hooks"

instead of

> git config --global core.hooksPath 'C:\Path\To\Hooks'

everything works as expected.